# how to compare href to div id

Tags: jquery

I have a page that check a querystring and adds an active to the the link on that page, 
but what I need to do is where that link has the ".active" to then show the corresponding div that has the same id as the "active" href, can't seem to figure how to match/compare to do this.

This only happens when you first load the page. Can anyone help.

```
    $(".container").hide();

if($("div").is(".display-sections")){
    if ($("a").is(".active")) {
        var activeContainer = $("div").is(".container")[0].attr("href").replace('#','');
        alert(activeContainer);
    $("#" + activeContainer).show();
    }
} 
<div id="help" class="display-sections">
         <ul class="subnav">
             <li><a href="#contact" class="trigger " id="link01">Contact</a></li>  
             <li><a href="#bingocalls" class="trigger active" id="link02">Bingo Calls</a></li>
             <li><a href="#bingolingo" class="trigger " id="link03">Bingo Lingo</a></li>
             <li><a href="#bingoglossary"  class="trigger " id="link04">Bingo Glossary</a></li>
         </ul>

           <div id="contact" class="container">
            <h2>Get in Contact</h2>
                 <div class="contentarea">
                    <div class="content_bg"></div>
                 </div>
            </div>

           <div id="bingocalls" class="container">
             <h2>Bingo Calls</h2>
             <div class="contentarea">
                <div class="content_bg"></div>
           </div>


             <div id="bingolingo" class="container">

             <h2>Bingo Lingo</h2>
             <div class="contentarea">
                <div class="content_bg"></div>
             </div>
             </div>


             <div id="bingoglossary" class="container">

             <h2>Bingo Glossary</h2>
             <div class="contentarea">
                <div class="content_bg"></div>
             </div>
             </div
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this code will help you:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $(".container").hide();
   $($(".subnav .active").attr("href")).show();
});
```